# What are Atipurana. What are the names of these Purana?

Tags: puranas

I received a classification of Purana from authorities like

1.**MahaPurana**

2.**UpPurana**

3. **Atipurana**

Can Anyone Tell Me briefly. What are **Atipurana**.

I share you a link :-***https://www.quora.com/The-classification-Satvic-Rajasic-and-Tamasic-is-made-of-the-18-Maha-Puranas-There-are-lists-but-is-there-any-content-analysis-to-justify-the-Guna-of-any-purana-except-to-arbitrarily-call-Vishnu-puranas-satvik-and-Shiva-puranas-tamasic***
In last words of this article I found it. Give me Answer peacefully